# Counter in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Designing a counter mod60 in VHDL, I realized that something strange happens, but I can't explain why.
This image shows the moment of the transition from 59 to 00 (numbers converted to a 7SegDisp):

[image: Transition from 59 to 00]

The code for it is:

```
ENTITY Contador IS  --"Contador" means counter
    PORT(
        clk: IN BIT;
        disp_uni, disp_dez: OUT BIT_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END Contador;
--------------------
ARCHITECTURE Contador OF Contador IS
    ------
    SIGNAL unidade: NATURAL RANGE 0 TO 10; --units
    SIGNAL  dezena:  NATURAL RANGE 0 TO 6; --tens

    COMPONENT ConvDisp IS
        --display conversor's entity goes here
    );
    END COMPONENT;
    -----

    BEGIN

        PROCESS (clk) BEGIN
            IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN
                unidade <= unidade + 1;
                IF (unidade = 9) THEN     --Realize that the condition is 9 and not 10
                    unidade <= 0;
                    dezena <= dezena + 1;
                    IF (dezena = 5) THEN  --Realize that the condition is 5 and not 6
                        dezena <= 0;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS;


        conv1: ConvDisp PORT MAP (unidade, disp_uni);
        conv2: ConvDisp PORT MAP (dezena, disp_dez);

END Contador;
```

That code works. My question is why, since the units are resetting when they arrive at 9, not 10, and tens are resetting when they arrive at 5, not 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postponed assignment semantics.

Change the units and tens to variables, which have immediate assignment semantics, and the circuit will do what you expect (instead of working).

Then change them back and learn why it works.

The reason for postponed assignment semantics is that signals, (unlike variables in both VHDL and other programming languages) are designed for inter-process communication, and thus issues of race conditions, glitches, non-determinism and even potential deadlocks are important.

Signal assignment semantics (postponed assignment) along with delta cycles, are an elegant solution to this problem, and one of the most fundamental concepts in VHDL.

Learn this thoroughly and VHDL will make much more sense and be easier to write.

Yet it doesn't seem to be very well taught.

Here's [my take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532) on it, which may help.

Answer (score 1):

VHDL, and more accurately, the clocked-logic system it is used to design, generally describes procedures that determine the next state of the logic following an appropriate clock cycle.  So, you don't design the logic to say, "59 rolls over to 60, and then we see 60 and change it to 00", rather, we say "we are at 59, it is going to roll over to 60, so instead we will roll it to 00".

In other words, you look at the current state and you decide what the next state will be.  So, 59 -> 00 is the correct transition.

And you might wonder as well, how transitioning the 9 to a 0 doesn't confuse the logic that's looking for 59 going to 60.  The reason is that all of the states are analyzed and the next states are set up before the clock occurs.  Nothing actually changes until that clock edge arrives.  So you can decide what the one's digit will become, and you can separately decide what the ten's digit will become.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. "Nothing actually changes" until the end of the current delta cycle, which is too late for the current clock edge  - i.e. nominally 0 femtoseconds after it. It's just that, in the existing design, the changes aren't *looked at* by *this process* until the next clock edge.